# Determine number of varying elements in 2nd dimension of bash associative array?

Tags: bash, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D associative array where the number of elements in the second dimension varies for each element in the first dimension. The number of rows and columns per row varies with each runtime.  (Just FYI, the rows are files, the first element of the 2nd dimension is each filename, and the subsequent elements are the data from the files.)

I can count the number of elements in the second dimension as I load the array and store that in another array - which works - but I've tried multiple search strings for over a couple of days and can't find out how to know how many elements there are dynamically in each second dimension so I can iterate through them later.  Is there some better built-in or other dynamic way to know?

Please assume there is an overriding reason I'm (A) doing this in bash and (B) using arrays instead of manipulating the data in the files and using bash's wonderful text processing commands. Thanks.

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A Matrix
num_rows=3
declare -a NumCols
# num_columns=VARIES BY EACH ROW

Matrix[0,0]="Row0"
Matrix[0,1]="Bob"
Matrix[0,2]="Joe"
Matrix[0,3]="Millie"
NumCols[0]=3  # Yes, should be 4 but element 0 is a label for the following data
Matrix[1,0]="Row1"
Matrix[1,1]="Fred"
Matrix[1,2]="Tommy"
NumCols[1]=2
Matrix[2,0]="Row2"
Matrix[2,1]="Alice"
Matrix[2,2]="Nancy"
Matrix[2,3]="Milton"
Matrix[2,4]="Carl"
NumCols[2]=4

# Can I replace NumCols[$i] with an expression?
for ((i=0;i<num_rows;i++)); do
    for ((j=1;j<=NumCols[$i];j++)); do
        echo "${Matrix[$i,0]} : ${Matrix[$i,$j]}"
    done
done

# DESIRED/ACTUAL OUTPUT FOR THIS EXAMPLE
Row0 : Bob
Row0 : Joe
Row0 : Millie
Row1 : Fred
Row1 : Tommy
Row2 : Alice
Row2 : Nancy
Row2 : Milton
Row2 : Carl
```

Comment: There is no way that's better than this in Bash, but if you really want to you can iterate over *all* keys and count the ones that e.g. start with `2,`

Comment: Nah, I was just wondering if there were equivalent expressions (length, number of elements, etc.) for multidimensional associative arrays as there are for regular arrays.  Looking to learn something new that I couldn't find on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual code I currently use to load the arrays with the data and count.  Maybe I threw you guys off with my example.  I'll actually process 30-70 input files (rows) and each file will have 1-120 data elements (columns).  Once the data is loaded I do something fairly complex with it and my actual output is quite different from the example.  I was trying to leave out the complexity and provide an example focused on the core issue - knowing the variable number of columns in each row during later processing - but maybe I did that poorly.  Are these answers better for my goal?  It could easily be that I'm just not understanding them correctly.  Thanks.

```
declare -A Watchlist
declare -a WlStkCount
declare WLcount=0


# Load all watchlists into Watchlist array
LoadWatchLists () {
local WLindex=0
local indicator

# loop through all CSV files and load arrays with their data
for CSVfile in *.csv ;
    do
        indicator="${CSVfile%.*}"   # get indicator name
        STKindex=0
        Watchlist[$WLindex,$STKindex]="$indicator" 

        # loop through the stocks in $CSVfile
        # load array with sorted symbols to help later processing
        for StockSymbol in `tail -n +5 "$CSVfile" | cut -d"," -f1 | sort`;
            do
                let "STKindex++"
                Watchlist[$WLindex,$STKindex]="$StockSymbol"
            done

        WLStkCount[$WLindex]=$STKindex     # Nbr of stocks for indicator
        let "WLindex++"
    done
    WLcount=$WLindex
    # Finished loading indicators' stocks into array
}

# A simple example of outputting unprocessed data
for ((i=0;i<WLcount;i++)); do
    for ((j=1;j<=WLStkCount[$i];j++)); do
        echo "${Watchlist[$i,0]} : ${Watchlist[$i,$j]}"
    done
done
```

Comment: So my original question seems to be answered.  Just like bash provides the function of multidimensional arrays with associative arrays, I asked if they also provided functional counterparts to array methods to find count, length, etc.  That appears not to be the case so I'll mark my own answer as best as soon as stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: Just finished rewriting my software to use bash associative arrays instead of temporary text files (thousands of intermediate text files) and this version runs in 2.5 minutes instead of 25 hours!  bash may have no concept of associate arrays but they sure are efficient and effective.  :o)

Answer (score 0):

By making use of the reference capability of bash, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

mat_set() {
    local -n ref="Matrix$1"
    ref[$2]=$3
}

mat_get() {
    local -n ref="Matrix$1"
    echo "${ref[$2]}"
}

mat_numcol() {
    local -n ref="Matrix$1"
    echo "${#ref[@]}"
}

mat_set 0 0 "Row0"
mat_set 0 1 "Bob"
mat_set 0 2 "Joe"
mat_set 0 3 "Millie"

mat_set 1 0 "Row1"
mat_set 1 1 "Fred"
mat_set 1 2 "Tommy"

mat_set 2 0 "Row2"
mat_set 2 1 "Alice"
mat_set 2 2 "Nancy"
mat_set 2 3 "Milton"
mat_set 2 4 "Carl"

num_rows=3
for ((i=0; i<num_rows; i++)); do
    for ((j=1; j<$(mat_numcol "$i"); j++)); do
        echo "$(mat_get "$i" 0) : $(mat_get "$i" "$j")"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
Row0 : Bob
Row0 : Joe
Row0 : Millie
Row1 : Fred
Row1 : Tommy
Row2 : Alice
Row2 : Nancy
Row2 : Milton
Row2 : Carl
```

Note that it assumes the indices of the 2nd dimension are linearly aligned (without a gap). Otherwise we will need another approach.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that idea but I'm not sure it's better for my real application.  See my answer on how I initially load the data into the array.  If you think this is better or more efficient for the goal - knowing how many columns are in a given row during later processing - please educate me.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bash only has one dimensional arrays (both numerically indexed ones and associative ones), the burden is completely on you to manage things that you are interpreting as additional dimensions.

But you can count your entries as you make the assignments:

```bash
num_rows=0  # Note: line changed from original, count will be correct after assignments are complete
start=-1
col=$start


nextitem() {
  Matrix[num_rows,++col]=$1
}

nextrow() {
  NumCols[num_rows]=$col
  col=$start
  if [[ $1 != last ]]
  then
    (( num_rows++))
  fi
}

nextitem "Row0"
nextitem "Bob"
nextitem "Joe"
nextitem "Millie"
nextrow

nextitem "Row1"
nextitem "Fred"
nextitem "Tommy"
nextrow

nextitem "Row2"
nextitem "Alice"
nextitem "Nancy"
nextitem "Milton"
nextitem "Carl"
nextrow last
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now.  It works but I thought there might a bash array feature for multidimensional arrays like there is for standard arrays.  Thanks.

Comment: @TomA: As I noted in my answer, Bash has no concept of multidimensional arrays. Whenever data structures are required that outstrip Bash's capabilities, I recommend switching to a richer language such as Python.

Comment: As previously noted, there are good reasons for my choice at this time.  If I rewrite it I'll probably go with C++.